# Laravel File equivalent in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I can access the list of files in a directory in Laravel using this:

```
use File;
....
$files = File::files($path);
```

However, I get this error in lumen:

```
Class 'File' not found
```

Any idea how I can access list of files in a folder in lumen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

File is only avaiable in Laravel by default. Although you can still used it on Lumen Framework by doing the following.

1. Enable the facade in `boostrap/app.php` by uncommenting the following code.

`$app->withFacades();`

2. After that, you will be able to access the File class in any of your controller by adding it as:

`use Illuminate\Http\File;`

or you can use the Facade Class.

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;`

3. Please do a `composer dump-autoload` to update autoload.

Comment: Hi...Thanks for your answer but I get this error now "FatalThrowableError in FileAccessController.php line 28:Class 'Illuminate\Http\File' not found".

Comment: Sorry, please see the updated answer. Please try running a `composer dump-autoload` command. You probably need to use the 

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;`